Safest fuses to tap for a 3 wire dash cam on a VW Golf Mk7 (2017)
On A 2017, right hand drive Golf Mk7, what are the "safest choices" to tap when installing a 3 wire dash camera hard wire kit using piggyback blade adapter.

Wire 1 requires always on power for parking detection
Wire 2 requires ignition only power for recording while driving
Wire 3 connects to the chassis stud.


By safest, I means fuses that do not power systems required for the vehicle's basic functions, such as breaks and steering, or critical safety systems such as air bags.
Alternatively, are there any fuses that should not be tapped under any curcumstances.
I specify want to avoid using the cigarette lighter power supply as this has been converted into a power breakout for another device, and I want it on a separate supply from the dash cam so that if one fails I still have a separate in cabin power supply.
I have seen multiple conflicting tutorials on which fuses to use, most from left hand drive vehicles.

I believe you are thinking about this wrong, mainly because the side you want to tap is the power side of the fuse. This is the side of the fuse power is delivered to it. If you use the opposite side, you're actually using the fuse as well, which can cause it to be overloaded with the camera's draw as well as the vehicle accessory draw. Here's what you need to do instead.
First, you need inline fuses for your camera on both sides (always active and keyed on) wires. This is to protect your device and the vehicle.
Next, with a multimeter and the vehicle keyed off, start checking the fuses for power. This will tell you whether the circuit is live or not with the key off. Check several fuses and find an active one which has the highest value for fuse protection. To figure out which side the power is actually coming from, pull the fuse and check the slots to see which side is powered. This is the side you want to tap off of so you're not overloading the fuse in the panel.
You'll want to use a larger fused circuit, like the 30A or 40A fuses, for your keyed on power source. This is because this circuit is rated for a higher load and can most likely handle it. Once again, find the powered side of the fuse and use it for your fuse tap.
Depending on what type of fuse tap you're using will dictate how it's installed. There are two primary types I'm aware of. First is like this:

This would go on the powered side as I suggested and slips over the leg of the fuse. The second type is like this:

The wired side of the tap would go to the powered side of the fuse. Remember, if using this type, you still need a separate inline fuse so as to protect the vehicle, vehicle accessory, and camera.
For the third wire, you can utilize any grounding (earth) source you can find. You may have to run a ground wire if the camera wire is not long enough.

I think that you may have misunderstood what I'm asking. I have two fuse taps, like your second image, each with two fuses in. One for the original device being powered and one for the dash cam that is being piggyback on it. These only go in one way. The end without the wire goes in the live side. I'm asking which socket to plug the tap into.

@AaarghZombies - I think you misunderstand my answer. The purpose of it is to provide you a sure way to get what you need versus someone else's second guess you've pulled off the internet. This will work for ANY vehicle in any situation, versus just giving you a "this is where you should place it" answer. You said you've had problems with other people's suggestions because of left hand drive differences. This method will give you the way to do it without those differences.

OK, but but why are you talking about the side of the fuse? Fuses only go in one way. I'm looking for help to avoid piggybacking off of a critical system. I don't understand how your answer addresses this. Your answer just seems to say that I can plug in anywhere so long as I have the correct fuse rating.

The power goes in one side and is used by the device from the other side. If you tap the power coming INTO the fuse instead of going out of the fuse. you aren't leaving a "critical system" in danger. And yes, you can just plug it in anywhere so long as you're tapping off the correctly side of the fuse. And you're not correct ... the fuse tap can go two ways. Plug it in with the pigtail oriented to one side or the other ... that's two different ways of installing it. You want the pig tail to be on the side which is providing power, not the other side which is using it.

I think that you have misunderstood the question. I'm simply asking which of the fuses it is safe to piggy back off of. I'm not asking about the physical install process. The thing you mrntio8are all in the manual, but the manual doesn't say which sockets are safe to use.

I'm looking for answers along the lines of "don't connect it to you air bag fuse"

@AaarghZombies - If you put it on the CORRECT side of the fuse, you have no worry about whether its the airbag fuse or the fuel injection pump. Why is this? Because if you put it on the power side of the fuse, you have no worries about burning out the fuse going to the air bags or what have you. This is what you need to worry about which will allow you not to worry about it in the first place. I gave you an answer that completely satisfies your question, yet isn't exactly what you asked. Don't let your preconceived notions of what you are planning to do drive what you should do.

@AaarghZombies What you are not grasping from Paulster's answer is that on the array of fuses, for each fuse, one side goes directly to the battery (through a larger 50-100 amp fuse or a breaker) and the other side goes to the circuit that the fuse is protecting. As long as you connect to the correct side -- the side with voltage when you pull the fuse -- you are not using or interfering with the circuit that the fuse is protecting. You're going straight to the battery. So it truly doesn't matter which fuse you pick as long as it is constant or switched as you need it.

@MTA, with all due respect, most of the installation guides from the manufacturers say that it is important which fuse is used. They say categorically not to install fuse taps on any critical systems.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, I'm a little worried as to why you formatted your answer as a tutorial on installing a fuse tap, rather than an answer saying that the exact fuse tapped is not important for reasons XYZ. When the question is asking for "where" and the answer says "how", it reads very much like the person hasn't understood what is being asked. Are you able to rewrite the answer to be more closely related to the question?

@AaarghZombies Yes, installation guides are written for dummies, which is no reflection on you, it's just the way of the world. Paulster's method, with the caveat to use the correct side, is superior in every way and eliminates all such worries since NO circuits are "tapped". You go to the battery side, not the fused side. But it's your car and your choice. Best wishes.

Think of it like this-  You've got a big power wire coming off the battery that goes to the fuse panel.  From there, the power splits out to multiple fuses that power different devices.   What you want to do is connect to the power BEFORE it gets to the fused circuits.  It's basically like running a second power wire directly from the battery to what you want to power, except you can get the same thing from connecting to the POWER SIDE of any fuse.

@AaarghZombies - The answer isn't a how to on using a tap, but rather a how to on finding the fuse you're looking to use. Again, you're the one which stated the information you found online isn't pointing directly at what tap to use or is askew from left to right hand drives. The information I've provided gives you a way to figure this out for yourself without making mistakes. You don't need anyone to tell you which exactly, because you'll have figured it out for yourself.

@MTA if you go to the battery side, don't you instead risk that the combined load from the camera and whatever else was on the circuit will overload the wire on the battery side of the tap without blowing either fuse?

@DanIsFiddlingByFirelight Mmmm yeah, ok in theory, but in practice that would only happen if you're installing a high current accessory like a popcorn maker for those nights at the drive-in movies. For ordinary electronics we're dealing with mA to very low amps, so it's a non-issue. Good catch though!

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 OK, but what I'm taking issue with are people answering different questions form the one that was asked. If the question was "how do I determine which fuses are live only when the ignition is on" then you're answer would be spot on. Likewise with "figuring it out for yourself", it's good answer, but it's for a different question than the one which was asked.

@AaarghZombies - Not going to argue about it ... it does answer your question, just not in the way you want it answered. It will also answer for others as well who don't own a Golf.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2♦, I'm going to disagree on the grounds that the answer was how to tell the difference between an always on and an ignition only fuse, whereas the question was about selecting between the different fuses within those groups. It's predicated on there being several choices available for each type of fuse and wanting to choose within those groups.

One way to determine which fuses are always HOT and other fuses switched on with ignition would be separating them to two types of circuits. For always ON power; headlights, fog lights, brake lights. For switched power; everything else (seat heater, wiper washer, defrost, hvac blower, ac, etc.. There may be empty slots with either HOT or switched power to choose from.  Using a multimeter will help. There should be a fuse guide embossed into the fuse cover as well as owner's manual. If cabin fuses are installed, more choices. Choose the largest fused circuit for wire-1/HOT and wire-2/switched power. I'm guessing dashcams draw less than a few amps and shouldn't strain 10/15/20/25/30/40 amp wired circuits.

I was more asking along the lines of which fuses it was safe to piggyback. For example, ABS and air bags are obviously not good choices, but heated seats?

If you have heated seats, those are applied power when ignition is switched on since leaving heated seats turned on, If not switched off by the heated switch or the ignition switch, would easily kill a car battery in a few hours. If you lose heated seats, the main reason for losing it are damage to the heating elements in the seat and/or seat back, not blowing its fuse. In cold weather, the main source of heat is the hvac heating system and blower speed. Losing heated seats from a blown fuse is just an inconvenience.
